# Attaching doc file in email php?

Tags: php, email, doc

I use the following code to attach the file through email, email is received with attachment symbol but opening the mail doesnot contain anything.

```
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $from = "test@domainname.com"; 
    $headers = "From: " . $fromEmailName . " ". "\r\n" ;

    $headers .= "cc: " . $fromEmailName . " <" . $cc . ">" . "\r\n" ;



   $boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

   // headers used for send attachment with email
   $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"           {$boundary}\"";


  $message = "--{$boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-  Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
  $message .= "--{$boundary}\n";


   $fileatt = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; // Path to the tmp file
   $fileatt_type = "text/plain"; // File Type
   $fileatt_name = "upload.doc"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment
   $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
  $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
  fclose($file); 

  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
  $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
 "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$fname\"\n" .
 "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
  $message .= "--{$boundary}\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f " . $from)
```

Comment: Nothing against writing code yourself but is there a good reason you don't use a well tested library like [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) for this? Your approach seems to be very error prone to me.

Comment: You shouldn't have `{"..."}` around `application/octet-stream`

Comment: Instead use all this stuff to send an email, try to use PHPMailer. (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Thank vitor luis finnaly php mailer saved my day